# How to write this IF condition correctly, inside WHERE clause codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, where-clause

I am using **`codeigniter`**, I want to use an IF condition in WHERE clause. But it is not executing properly.

```
$where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR ( IF(c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1,'a.LastName LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\'  OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\' ','')))";
$this->db->where($where_string);
```

i am doing a search here . by `first name` , `last name` and `first name` **concat** `last name` .

i check the value `c.PrivacySettingsElephantiUser` . if only it is true , i am cheking for last name and first name last name concat value , the thing is if the `c.PrivacySettingsElephantiUser=1` AND`c.PrivacySettingsElephantiUser=0`,

this part is not executing .

`OR ( IF(c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1,'a.LastName LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\'  OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\' ','')`

it is only searching by the first name always , ignoring the if condition ,

How to write this correctly?

Is there an easy way to do this using `AND ,OR` logic?

**UPDATE**

this my full query

```
public function search_people($profile_id,$search_phrase=NULL,$country=NULL,$state=NULL,$city=NULL,$neighborhood=NULL,$type=NULL,$limit=NULL,$offset=NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.ProfileID,a.FirstName,a.LastName,a.StateName,a.CityName,a.ShowLastName,a.UserType,a.ProfileImg,b.FriendStatus,b.RequesterID,b.AccepterID',FALSE);
    $this->db->from($this->mastables['xxxxxxxx'].' as a');
$this->db->join($this->mastables['yyyyyyyyyyy'].' as b'," b.RequesterID=a.ProfileID AND b.AccepterID=".$profile_id." OR b.AccepterID=a.ProfileID AND b.RequesterID=".$profile_id,'left');


    $this->db->where('a.ProfileID !=',$profile_id);
    $this->db->where('a.UserType',2);

    if($type=="friend")
    {

        $this->db->join($this->mastables['profile_privacy_settings'].' as c'," c.EntityID=a.ProfileID AND c.UserType=2 AND c.ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID=1 ",'inner');
        $where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR ( IF(c.PrivacySettingFriend=1,'a.LastName LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\'  OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\' ','')))";
        $this->db->where($where_string);
        $this->db->where('b.FriendStatus',1);
    }
    else if($type=="other")
    {
        $this->db->join($this->mastables['profile_privacy_settings'].' as c'," c.EntityID=a.ProfileID AND c.UserType=2 AND c.ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID=1 ",'inner');
        $where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR ( IF(c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1,'a.LastName LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\'  OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\' ','')))";
        $this->db->where($where_string);
        $this->db->where ('(b.FriendStatus IS NULL OR b.FriendStatus=0)');
    } else {    
        $this->db->join($this->mastables['profile_privacy_settings'].' as c'," c.EntityID=a.ProfileID AND c.UserType=2 AND c.ProfilePrivacySettingDefaultID=1 ",'inner');
        $where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR ( IF(c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1 OR c.PrivacySettingFriend=1,'a.LastName LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\'  OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\'','')))";
        //$where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR ( IF(c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1 OR c.PrivacySettingFriend=1,'a.LastName LIKE b%','')))";
        $this->db->where($where_string);
    }

    if($country)
    {
        $this->db->where('a.CountryID',$country);
    }
    if($state)
    {
        $this->db->where('a.StateID',$state);
    }
    if($city)
    {
        $this->db->where('a.CityID',$city);
    }
    if($neighborhood)
    {
        //$this->db->where('',$neighborhood);
    }
    if($limit)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);   
    }

$query = $this->db->get();
//echo $this->db->last_query();die;
$result['result'] = $query->result_array();

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `Count`');
    $result["totalrows"] = $query->row()->Count;

if(!empty($result))
{
    return $result; 
}
}
```

Comment: I think you can't use `sql expressions` in if condition, may be that's the reason use `CASE` instead as @manurajhada said

Comment: @junaid , please show me , how , i tried but giving errors

Comment: try this- `$where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR ( 
 CASE 
  WHEN c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser = 1 THEN 
   'a.LastName LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\'  OR 
    CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) LIKE \'".$search_phrase."%\' '
    ELSE ''
    )))";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not getting PHP operations just writing sql code.. Use [Case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement in your where query

```
case when (c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1 AND (a.LastName LIKE '%something%' 
OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) like '%something%') then 1 else 0 end;
```

Comment: hmm, how to apply this to my code , i tried by    $where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR  (case when (c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1 AND (a.LastName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) like '".$search_phrase."%') then 1 else 0 end )))";
but it is failing

Comment: try this.. 
    `$where_string="( a.FirstName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR (case when (c.PrivacySettingElephantiUser=1 AND (a.LastName LIKE '".$search_phrase."%' OR CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) like '".$search_phrase."%')) then 1 else 0 end ))";`

Comment: works when remove \ in CONCAT(a.FirstName, \' \', a.LastName) . thank you very much .